# работа с очень большими числами

Tags: c#

Есть проблема, решаю задачи на codewars и в задаче где нужно поменять цифры числа на 0 или 1 в зависимости от условия, 0 если цифра меньше 5 и 1 если цифра больше 5, мне выдаёт ошибку когда я пытаюсь распарсить входную строку которая представляет громадное число через int.Parse, говорит что число слишком большое чтобы храниться в типе int, BigInteger не дал никаких результатов
Вот код решения задачи:

```
static string FakeBinary(string number)
        {
            string output = "";
            BigInteger integerRepresentation = int.Parse(number);
            int[] digitsArray = new int[number.Length];
            for (int i = 0;i <digitsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                int currentDigit = (int)integerRepresentation % 10;
                integerRepresentation /= 10;
                if (currentDigit > 5)
                {
                    digitsArray[digitsArray.Length - i -1] = 1;
                }
                else if (currentDigit < 5)
                {
                    digitsArray[digitsArray.Length - i - 1] = 0;
                }
                output += digitsArray[i];
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Текст задачи: Given a string of digits, you should replace any digit below 5 with '0' and any digit 5 and above with '1'. Return the resulting string.
С малыми числами работает, но с числом к примеру "366058562030849490134388085" падают тесты что на codewars, подскажите что делать?
Вот вторая версия моего кода, но почему-то оно когда я обращаюсь к отдельному символу берёт целиком всю строку и всегда возвращает единицу при проверки условия

```
static string FakeBinary1(string number)
        {
            //for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    Console.Write(number[i]);
            //}
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                if (number[i] < 5)
                {
                    output += 0;
                }
                else if (number[i] > 5)
                {
                    output += 1;
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Comment: ulong используйте

Comment: @Aarnihauta взял ulong и начал number[i] приводить к ulong, всё верно? Если да, то всё равно не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a **string** of digits,

Зачем Вам переводить всю строку в число? Идите по строке и проверяйте каждую цифру.

Зачем Вам массив `digitsArray`?

---

```
if ((number[i] - '0') < 5) {
  ...
```

Comment: А можно обращать так чтобы char[i] в строке приводился к типу int и затем сравнивался с 5 и в зависимости от условия становился 0 или 1?

Comment: @Mark Можно обращать.

Comment: static string FakeBinary1(string number)
        {
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                if (number[i] < 5)
                {
                    output += 0;
                }
                else if (number[i] > 5)
                {
                    output += 1;
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
Вот как теперь делаю решение, но получаю везде 1, даже если число меньше 5, по условиями вроде все правильно, не знаю в чём проблема

Comment: Подскажите как в комментарии сделать так чтобы код нормально отображался?

Comment: полез в отладчик, и смотрю что оно берёт целиком всю строку, а не отдельно каждый символ, можете подсказать в чём проблема?

Comment: попробовал я вывести строку входную отдельно по символам, оно нормально берёт каждый символ в отдельности и выводит, не понимаю в чём проблема с другим фором где я тоже обращаюсь к символам по одному за раз

Comment: а почему вы делаете - '0', я сделал как вы говорите, и оно стало работать, но я не знаю почему оно стало работа сразу как я добавил как вы сказали

Comment: @Mark посмотрите в таблицу символов ASCII. Каждый символ имеет код, char при математических операциях неявно преобразуется в int как числовой код символа. В таблице цифры расположены по порядку, а это значит, что можно делать математику с кодами со смещением на код символа '0'. Это должно быть очень просто.

Comment: @aepot я знаю что char это вроде как на самом деле число которое является кодом символа из таблицы ASCII, но я также думал что если мы берём char то оно там само по умолчанию приводится к int и я думал что этого достаточно и не нужно никакого смещения. Плюс я не очень понял, там смещение считается с кодами символов, если я правильно понял

Comment: @aepot может быть когда идёт это самое вычитание там остаётся разность кода цифры текущей и кода символа 0, а затем это разность записывается как число, но тогда остаётся вопрос почему же когда я обращаюсь отдельному символу строки берётся всё число, а не отдельный символ, когда я обращаюсь к символу по индексу?

Comment: @Mark вы близко, подумайте еще. Создайте новое приложение, поотлаживайте математику с символами. `int zero = '0';` и т.д. Разберетесь быстро, я уверен, это очень просто.

Comment: @aepot всё, понял в чём было дело, надо во-первых было, в задании чтобы уточнили что делать если цифра 5, и если текущая цифра >= 5 то ставим 1, это первое, а второе я вроде как правильно понял что там разница кодов символов, спасибо за подсказки, тесты прошли